# Cannot use correct value in correct generic type

Tags: java

I have a HashMap which doesn't allow me to use the getOrDefault method on the hashmap. Here is my code:

```
 public static HashMap<String, Integer> getInputWords(String location) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(location);
        BufferedReader bFReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        String line = bFReader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            String[] strs = line.split(" ");
            for(String tmp : strs) {
                wordCount.put(tmp.toLowerCase(), getOrDefault(tmp.toLowerCase(), Integer.valueOf(0)) + 1); //error on getOrDefault method.
            }
            line = bFReader.readLine();
        }
        bFReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

The method is giving me an error of:

> The method getOrDefault(String, Integer) is undefined for the type Main07

(Main07 is my class).

Comment: We need to see your getOrDefault method in order to answer your question.

Comment: where is your getOrDefault method? if this method doesn't exist,surely the error message will appear .

Comment: This is the method, it is part of the HashMap class.V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)
Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Comment: Ignore me, I don't know what I was thinking... I wasn't calling it off of my HashMap...

Comment: Add `wordCount.` in front of getordefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOrDefault()` is a `HashMap` method , so call it on your `HashMap`.

```
wordCount.getOrDefault(tmp.toLowerCase(), Integer.valueOf(0))
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that, thank you for pointing it out... I spent a good half hour and asked a friend about it... Been a long day lol